# Cannot save - load xml_document generated from rvest in R

Tags: r, xml, rvest

The `read_html` function generates an xml_document which i would like to save and later on load it to parse it.

The problem is that after loading the xml_document there is no html within it.

```
library(rvest)
library(magrittr)
doc <- read_html("http://www.example.com/")
doc %>% html_node("h1") %>% html_text
```

I get: `[1] "Example Domain"`

But when I save first the xml_document `doc` object and load it again it seems that everything has been cleared.

```
save(doc, file=paste0(getwd(), "/example.RData"))
rm(doc)

load(file=paste0(getwd(), "/example.RData"))
doc %>% html_node("h1") %>% html_text
```

I get: `Error: No matches`

Or when i run `doc` i get: `{xml_document}` an empty xml_document.

It is also the case that when i run the `doc`, after having loaded it,  i get a message that RStudio has stopped working.

I have tried it on two different windows machines, got the same problem.

```
sessionInfo()

R version 3.3.0 (2016-05-03)
Platform: x86_64-w64-mingw32/x64 (64-bit)
Running under: Windows 7 x64 (build 7601) Service Pack 1

locale:
[1] LC_COLLATE=English_United Kingdom.1252  LC_CTYPE=English_United Kingdom.1252   
[3] LC_MONETARY=English_United Kingdom.1252 LC_NUMERIC=C                           
[5] LC_TIME=English_United Kingdom.1252    

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

other attached packages:
[1] magrittr_1.5     rvest_0.3.1.9000 xml2_0.1.2      

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
[1] httr_1.1.0  R6_2.1.2    tools_3.3.0 Rcpp_0.12.5
```

Comment: I ran into the same error. [I have opened an issue on Github](https://github.com/hadley/rvest/issues/181).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have found a workaround, not very efficient but it does the job.

The logic is to save the `xml_document` as a string and read it in again with `read_html`.

```
library(rvest)
library(magrittr)
doc <- read_html("http://www.example.com/")

# convert it to character
doc %<>% as("character")

save(doc, file=paste0(getwd(), "/example.RData"))
rm(doc)

load(file=paste0(getwd(), "/example.RData"))
doc %>% read_html %>% html_node("h1") %>% html_text
```

Answer (score 4):

I wrote some *ad hoc* functions to accomplish this task. They are slightly better than the previous answer because they work for lists of **rvest** objects and they use RDS instead of RData files. This allows one to name the object anything one wants.

```
write_rvest = function(x, path, ...) {
  #convert to character
  #is list?
  if (is.list(x)) {
    x %<>% map(as.character)
  } else {
    x %<>% as.character
  }

  #save
  write_rds(x, path = path, ...)
}

read_rvest = function(path) {
  #load from file
  x = read_rds(path)

  #read
  if (is.list(x)) {
    x %<>% map(read_html)
  } else {
    x %<>% read_html
  }

  x
}
```

Tests for equality work but fail for identity. Nevertheless, the objects work and they have the same size in bytes, so I don't know why identity fails. Maybe it's sensitive to RAM position.

Comment: Nice wrapper function. I am not closing the answer as accepted yet in case there is another alternative. Thanks

Comment: Let's wait and see if **rvest** devs will answer. :)

Comment: The same problem still exists, unfortunately

Answer (score 1):

Here the same wraper-function as by Deleet in base R code.

```
library(rvest)

write_rvest = function(x, file, ...) {
  #convert to character
  #is list?
  if (is.list(x)) {
    x = Map(as.character, x)
  } else {
    x = as.character(x)
  }

  #save
  saveRDS(x, file = file, ...)
}

read_rvest = function(file) {
  #load from file
  x = readRDS(file)

  #read
  if (is.list(x)) {
    x <- Map(read_html, x)
  } else {
    x <- read_html(x)
  }

  x
}
```

Comment: Seems like you repeated `x = Map(as.character, x)` for no reason (?).